# What is lost with Google IP Anonymization?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We can use [IP Anonymization](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ip-anonymization) to circumvent the need for providing GA Data in the event of the GDPR Subject Access Request.  Do we loose anything by doing this as far as GA features go?  Why is it not the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-consequenses-of-using-IP-Anonymization-in-Google-Analytics-from-a-digital-marketing-point-of-view) does a pretty good job of answering your question. Basically you will just be sacrificing some precision in your geographic reporting.

Comment: You can overcome the geographic precision if you have a client-side means of determining the location and send the [`geoid` parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#geoid) with your tracking code.